# Orders of operations (beyond PEMDAS)

Tags: notation, arithmetic

I am writing a toy mathematical expression parser/calculator, and I have to decide how to handle operator precedence. I realize there is no such thing as a universally agreed upon order of operations that covers everything, but I ask for input anyway, since some ordering/groupings will undoubtedly be less perplexing than others.

In no particular order, the operations I must group/sort are:

- parenthesis
- exponentiation
- functions (i.e. sqrt)
- double factorial and factorial
- unary plus and minus
- implied multiplication
- binary multiply, divide, and modulo
- binary plus and minus
- maybe comma for creating tuples and multivariable functions (e.g. atan2)

Edit: I actually was planning on just copying whatever Wolfram Alpha does, but it turns out it doesn't use a fixed order. Instead it tries to interpret your intent and that causes it to be inconsistent at times.

Comment: You may be interested in the [order adopted by some programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages).

Comment: [Here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Operator_precedence) is a page that mentions some more of the operations, including factorials. I agree that factorials should probably have high precedence. Implied multiplication is a tricky one! I think usually when this is treated as having an order of precedence, it is the same as explicit multiplication. I'm also not sure what you mean by "order of precedence of commas". There should only be one sensible way to interpret commas when you're parsing a mathematical expression.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Apparently Texas Instruments has handled implied multiplication both ways before. As for comma, I was planning on letting comma bind with the lowest precedence and have it form a tuple. So if you call `atan(x, y)` you are actually just using atan as a unary operator, and since comma binds lowest, you need the parathesis around `x, y` otherwise it would parse as a tuple of `(atan(x), y)`